# Worksheet Change event with data validation

Tags: excel, vba, validation

My VBA is not running once a cell data is changed.
On my worksheet I have VBA running in Column F and G.
Column G has data validation that I want to trigger based on the numerical value input in column F.

Example:
Column F has a numerical value of 2.5 which results in Column G displaying "Good Standing".
If I change the Column F value to < 2, I want Column G cell to show blank
and vice versa if Column F value is originally < 2, and I increase it to > 2 Column G will display "Good Standing.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    StrtRow = 2
    EndRow = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = StrtRow To EndRow
        If Range("F" & i).Value >= 2 Then
            Range("G" & i).Value = "Good Standing"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Currently your code will run through every cell in F whenever any cell is changed anywhere. You need to reference `Target` in your code which is the cell that has been changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an `Else` clause to clear the contents if `< 2`. Taking @SJR 's comment into account, try this (not tested)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngWatched As Range: Set rngWatched = Me.Range("F:F")
    Dim cl As Range
        
    If Not Intersect(rngWatched, Target) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        
        For Each cl In Intersect(rngWatched, Target)
            If cl.Value >= 2 Then
                cl.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Good Standing"
            Else
                cl.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
            End If
        Next
        
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @superSymmetry for your comment. That code does not seem to be performing the function I need. It still does not update once the cell change occurs.

Comment: Good point @SJR. Please follow [this](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/worksheet-change-event/) guide to insert the code in the correct module.

Comment: Ok, that was the issue. I had it in a separate module. I had to play around with another code to fit this one in and have them both running successfully. I truly appreciate both of your feedback and assisting me with my issue!